# GROUP BY clause - too many results

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have problems with a GROUP BY clause im MSSQL.

I am trying to get a result with only the newest idNotation (the max PublishedTime), but it shows results with dublicated idNotation...

This is my SQL

```
SELECT idAnalysis, idNotation, max(PublishedTime) AS PublishedTime, Created, 
       T2.Link, T3.Name AS Rec, V.NAME_SECURITY, V.PRICE
FROM Analysis T1
INNER JOIN Templates T2 ON T1.idTemplates = T2.idTemplates 
LEFT JOIN Recommendations T3 ON T1.idRecommendation = T3.idRecommendations
INNER JOIN RFD.dbo.vLiveQuotes V ON T1.idNotation = V.ID_NOTATION
WHERE PublishedTime is not null
      AND
      T2.idTemplates = 4
GROUP BY idNotation, idAnalysis, [Level], Goal, StopLoss, Header, [Resume],
         T2.Name, Created, T2.Link, T3.Name, V.NAME_SECURITY, V.PRICE
ORDER BY PublishedTime DESC
```

The result:

```
25  7239884 Akkumuler   DANSKE BANK A/S DKK10   93
24  7239884 Sælg    DANSKE BANK A/S DKK10   934.500
22  7490572 Sælg    A.P. MOLLER - MAERSK SER`B`DKK1000  43
23  7239884 Hold    DANSKE BANK A/S DKK10   93
18  2027313 Køb GENMAB AS DKK1 (BEARER) 41
```

But the result should be:

```
25  7239884 Akkumuler   DANSKE BANK A/S DKK10   93
22  7490572 Sælg    A.P. MOLLER - MAERSK SER`B`DKK1000  43
18  2027313 Køb GENMAB AS DKK1 (BEARER) 41
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your query correctly, you want the data from T1, T2 and T3, and only the last publication from V. To shorten things, T1, T2 and T3 will be looked at as a single table T. There are few options. Check them out and use the one that runs fastest in your situation.

Using [row_number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
select *
from T
inner join 
(
   select ID_NOTATION, V.NAME_SECURITY, V.PRICE, V.PublishedTime
          row_number() over (partition by ID_NOTATION 
                             order by PublishedTime desc) AS RowNumber
     from RFD.dbo.vLiveQuotes V
) V
  ON T.idNotation = V.ID_NOTATION
  and V.RowNumber = 1
```

Using [apply](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx)

```
select *
from T
cross apply
(
   select TOP 1 *
     from RFD.dbo.vLiveQuotes V
    where V.idNotation = T.ID_NOTATION
    order by PublishedTime desc
) V
```

If you are restricted to older Sql Server you might try this:

```
select *
from T
inner join 
(
   select * 
     from RFD.dbo.vLiveQuotes V
     inner join
     (
         select ID_NOTATION, max(V.PublishedTime) PublishedTIme
           from RFD.dbo.vLiveQuotes
          group by ID_NOTATION
     ) lastPublishedTime
       on V.ID_NOTATION = lastPublishedTime.ID_NOTATION
       and V.PublishedTime = lastPublishedTime.PublishedTIme
) V
  ON T.idNotation = V.ID_NOTATION
```

Inner join might be left joins and cross apply outer apply if you expect that there will not be matching rows in V.

**UPDATE: learned that PusblishedTime lives in Analysis.**

Simplest thing is to remove max/group by, add derived table of idNotations and max(PublishedTime) and join back to Analysis:

```
SELECT idAnalysis, t1.idNotation, T1.PublishedTime AS PublishedTime, Created, 
       T2.Link, T3.Name AS Rec, V.NAME_SECURITY, V.PRICE
FROM Analysis T1
INNER JOIN Templates T2 ON T1.idTemplates = T2.idTemplates 
LEFT JOIN Recommendations T3 ON T1.idRecommendation = T3.idRecommendations
INNER JOIN RFD.dbo.vLiveQuotes V ON T1.idNotation = V.ID_NOTATION
inner join
(
  select idNotation, max(V.PublishedTime) PublishedTIme
    from Analysis
   group by idNotation
) lastPublishedTime
  on T1.idNotation = lastPublishedTime.idNotation
  and t1.PublishedTime = lastPublishedTime.PublishedTime
WHERE PublishedTime is not null
      AND
      T2.idTemplates = 4
ORDER BY PublishedTime DESC
```

You might use any other option, but it would require rewritting of a query.

Comment: I can run this: 
`select *
from Analysis T
cross apply
(
   select TOP 1 *
     from RFD.dbo.vLiveQuotes V
    where V.ID_NOTATION = T.idNotation
    order by T.PublishedTime desc
) V
WHERE T.PublishedTime is not null
 AND
 T.idTemplates = 4
 ORDER BY T.PublishedTime DESC`

But i still get all the results.. Nothing is grouped.

Comment: Where is PublishedTime coming from?

Comment: Still gets me the error `Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'Analysis.PublishedTime' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`
EDIT: - Think i got it!! :-D

Comment: Remove group by. I forgot to do that.

Comment: Thank you so much! Have been struggling with this all day!

Answer (score 2):

You are grouping on `Level, Goal, StopLoss, Header, Resume, T2.Name`, but those columns are not in the select list.  Remove them from the `group by`.

Comment: Sorry, i removed them from the select to post a shorter list here. I only want to group on idNotation, but if I remove anything from the GROUP BY i get this error: "Column 'Analysis.idAnalysis' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: That error message means you removed idAnalysis from the `group by` list.  You should only remove columns that you are not using in the `select`

Comment: `code` SELECT idNotation, idAnalysis, [Level], Goal, StopLoss, Header, [Resume], T2.Name, Created, T2.Link, T3.Name, V.NAME_SECURITY, V.PRICE FROM Analysis T1
 INNER JOIN Templates T2 ON T1.idTemplates = T2.idTemplates 
 LEFT JOIN Recommendations T3 ON T1.idRecommendation = T3.idRecommendations
 LEFT JOIN RFD.dbo.vLiveQuotes V ON T1.idNotation = V.ID_NOTATION
 WHERE PublishedTime is not null
 AND
 T2.idTemplates = 4
 GROUP BY idNotation, idAnalysis, [Level], Goal, StopLoss, Header, [Resume], T2.Name, Created, T2.Link, T3.Name, V.NAME_SECURITY, V.PRICE
 ORDER BY MAX(PublishedTime) DESC `code`